# Looking at the "other" html properties on an element in Selenium

Tags: vb.net, selenium

I'm using Selenium to automate some very basic data entry tasks. Sadly I don't have any influence over the site on which the form is hosted.

I have a number of fields on the form that seem to only differ in fields that I don't know how to make Selenium look at. I find all of the fields on the page and can enter text into them as below:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim elements = browser.FindElementsByClassName("form-control")
For Each elemnt In elements
    Try
        elemnt.SendKeys(i)
    Catch
    End Try
    i += 1
Next
```

Unfortunately this isn't going to be a long-term solution though, as they might change the order of boxes or similar without notifying me. Is there any way to view the whole of the `<input ...>` tag?

A selection of the inputs are below:

```
<input class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" data-ng-model="sQuoteName" kdfapp="Quoting" kdfpage="createDeal" kdfid="dealName" style="">

<input kdfapp="quote" kdfpage="quote" kdfid="amEmail" type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" id="ciscoEmail" data-ng-model="data.suggestAm" placeholder="Email" style="">

<select name="sQuoteType" data-ng-model="sQuoteType" data-ng-change="changeQuoteType();" kdfapp="Quoting" kdfpage="createDeal" kdfid="selectedBuyingBehalf_xxx" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                    <option value="" class="ng-binding">Select</option>
                    <option value="2" class="ng-binding">Prime Contractor/Systems Integrator</option>
                    <option data-ng-show="stiEligible" value="1" class="ng-binding ng-hide">Solution Technology Integrator</option>
                     <option data-ng-show="partner.partnerBuyMthod == 'DIRECT'" value="3" class="ng-binding" style="">IT Service Provider (Outsourcing Deal)</option>
                </select>
```

The most useful descriptor seems to be `kdfid=`

Comment: Why can you use `//tag[@kdfid='xxxx']` to uniquely identify each of the elements. Try changing `elemnt.GetAttribute("kdfid")` in the current loop to see the `kdfid` of each field. Once you are confirmed that all the elements are accessed correctly using `kdfid` then you can update the script to use that property as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks `elemnt.GetAttribute("kdfid")` works perfectly - if you want to write an answer to that effect I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `GetAttribute` method to get the `Kdfid`.

Sample code:

```
   element.GetAttribute("kdfid")
```